# Getting results from Oracle stored procedure insertion through pyodbc

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc (version 3.0.7) to access an Oracle (version 11g) database.  We are writing stored procedures to handle the insertions.  The primary keys for inserted objects are assigned with triggers, so we want to get the newly-inserted object's primary key into python after the stored procedure is called by the python script. (Due to client requirements, we don't have the flexibility of changing database, libraries, etc.)

According to the pyodbc documentation, return (OUT) parameters in stored procedures are not supported.  Neither are stored functions.  The documentation suggests to add a SELECT statement to the end of a stored procedure to get results out.  However, we are new to SQL scripting, and Google searching for the last two days has turned up a lot of information for SQLServer and other databases, but next to nothing for Oracle.  Trying the SQLServer examples on the Oracle db has not been tremendously helpful, as the Oracle SQL Developer shows various errors with the syntax (DECLARE where one shouldn't be, INTO required for SELECT statements, etc.).

Ultimately, we want the stored procedure to insert a new object, and then we want to somehow get the newly-created primary key for that object.

Here is an example of a stored procedure that correctly inserts an object (note that if obj_id is given as "None" in python, then the object is assigned a new primary key by a trigger):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_an_obj (an_obj_id NUMBER) AS
  new_primary_key NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO OBJS (OBJ_ID) VALUES (an_obj_id) RETURNING OBJ_ID INTO new_primary_key;

  -- A SELECT statement should go here in order to get the new value for new_primary_key.
END insert_an_obj;
```

Supposedly, a SELECT statement at the end of the stored procedure will make it so the next time my script calls `cursor.fetchall()`, the script would get a list of whatever was selected.  However, I have been unable to get this to work.  Some failed SELECT examples (one of which might go in the stored procedure above in place of the SELECT comment) include the following:

```
-- These fail to compile because SQL Developer doesn't like them (though various sources online said that they work on SQLServer):
SELECT * FROM OBJS WHERE OBJ_ID=new_primary_key;
SELECT OBJ_ID FROM OBJS WHERE OBJ_ID=new_primary_key;
```

Like I said, I'm new to SQL, and likely I just need to know the proper syntax to get the SELECT statement working nicely in Oracle.  Any suggestions?  Or is there something that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Unlike SQL Server, you can't just put a `SELECT` in a stored procedure to return data to the client.  There is some additional syntax in 12.1 to support this sort of undeclared `OUT sys_refcursor` but since you've tagged this for 11g, that's not an option for you.  In 11g, the only way to return data from a stored procedure is to have an `OUT` parameter.

Comment: @JustinCave: I was afraid of that.  Great fun finding out that what we need to do is impeded by the very versions of software that the client requires... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Justin Cave in the comment above, "you can't just put a `SELECT` in a stored procedure to return data to the client."  At least not with Oracle 11g.  He continues:  "In 11g, the only way to regurn data from a stored procedure is to have an `OUT` parameter", which AFIK, not possible using version 3.0.7 of pyodbc.